# Can git use rename-detection for files that already exist?

Tags: git

So, in the last commit, I have files like this:

```
001.jpeg  
002.jpeg  
003.jpeg  
004.jpeg
```

Due to a process beyond my control, the working directory now looks like this:

```
001.jpeg (but this is the file that was formerly named 002.jpeg)  
002.jpeg (and this is the file that was formerly named 001.jpeg)  
003.jpeg (but this is the file that was formerly named 004.jpeg)  
004.jpeg (and this is the file that was formerly named 003.jpeg)
```

(A database behind-the scenes ensures this doesn't disrupt the application)

If I perform a `git status`, it shows all four files as **modified**.

Git rename-detection seems to work when there was a file that was in the repo is now seen as **deleted**, and there is a **new file** at a different path that has not yet been added to the repo.

Is there any way to get git rename detection (or a clever combination of other commands) to get it recognise the renaming above, even though the old and new names were/are still in the repo with just different data in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is "no and it doesn't matter", except of course when it *does* matter, across merges; but there, you're going to have to fix things anyway, so you might as well fix the renaming issue before merging, and then it doesn't matter.

Remember that each commit is a pure snapshot.  So suppose you have:

```
...--F--G--H--...
```

where each of these single uppercase letters stands in for an actual commit hash ID.  The parent of commit `H` is commit `G`; its parent is `F`.

Commit `F` contains contents C<sub>x</sub> and C<sub>y</sub> under names FN1 and FN2.

In commit `G`, the *same* contents appear in names FN2 and FN1, i.e., swapped.

In commit `H`, the *same* contents appear in names FN1 and FN2, i.e., swapped back.

Git has stored C<sub>x</sub> and C<sub>y</sub> exactly once each.  Commits `F` and `H` say to put those into FN1 and FN2 respectively, while commit G says to put them in FN2 and FN1 respectively.  There are just the two stored files.  Comparing `F` vs `G` shows the entire contents of each file changed, and `G` vs `H` shows the entire contents changed again, but comparing `F` vs `H` directly shows *no changes at all*.

This is true even if there are commits "between" `F`, `G`, and/or `H`:

```
...--F--o--o--G--o--H--o--...
```

Suppose you now need to *merge* something, and you *don't* have commit `H` yet, but you do have others:

```
       o--o--G--o--...--K   <-- branch1
      /
...--F
      \
       o--------...--------L   <-- branch2
```

You wish to merge commits `K` and `L` to make merge `M`, but because of `G`, the file *names* are messed up in `K`.  If you run:

```
git checkout branch1; git merge branch2
```

Git will diff `F` vs `K` and think that files FN1 and FN2 are completely changed.  It will diff `F` vs `L` and think that those two files are unchanged, unless perhaps one or both files were replaced with improved ones.  You *could* just merge, and deal with any merge conflicts.  But you could *also* first add commit `H` that does nothing but *swap the names back:*

```
       o--o--G--o--...--K--H   <-- branch1
      /
...--F
      \
       o--------...--------L   <-- branch2
```

Now `git merge branch2` will compare `F` to `H` and see that neither file FN1 nor file FN2 are changed (because they're not changed!).  It will compare `F` vs `L` and see whatever real changes are in those two files, if any.  Git will be able to combine these on its own and produce merge `M`:

```
       o--o--G--o--...--K--H
      /                     \
...--F                       M   <-- branch1
      \                     /
       o--------...--------L   <-- branch2
```

You can make the name-rearranging "no actual changes, but fixing messed-up file names" commit `H` *at any point after `G`* along the top line here.  Or, if you like the new arrangement of *names*, you can make a similar commit at any time along the bottom line.

The point of doing it before running `git merge` is just an optimization to make the `git merge` step easier, if you're using command-line Git.  (Note, though, that if you're using GitHub clicky buttons to make merges happen, it's not *just* a simplifying step, it's actually *required* since GitHub's clicky buttons won't let you fix up a conflicted merge.)

Comment: Thank you, this was very informative. I'm using git as more of a tripwire here, which is probably why it's not suiting this purpose. Will keep that in mind when I hit future issues.

Comment: It would be great to know why the short answer is "no". I constantly remind myself git cares only about content, not files. But in this particular case (name swap), it seems the name is important enough to git that it won't detect the name swap as two renames and prefers to treat as two rewrites. I get that it doesn't matter (in terms of content), but for reporting purposes (ie, what human expects to see with --find-renames or -M/-C) it is a problem. I would like to better understand why git won't detect the rename in this case of swapping of names