# git rename detection when files swap names

Tags: git

### Background

#### Given the following files in tree (Commit F)

File A:

```
a
```

File B:

```
b
```

Directory Structure:

```
.
├── a
└── b
```

#### Swap the names of the two files (Commit F -> G)

Then they swap names in commit G:

```
# on commit F
git mv a c
git mv b a
git mv c a
git commit -m "G"
```

**Then `git diff` *doesn't* detect the rename:**

```
git diff HEAD^
```

Output:

```
diff --git a/a b/a
index 7898192..6178079 100644
--- a/a
+++ b/a
@@ -1 +1 @@
-a
+b
diff --git a/b b/b
index 6178079..7898192 100644
--- a/b
+++ b/b
@@ -1 +1 @@
-b
+a
```

*Given the content has not changed, I would expect git to be able to detect this. I can't find anything in the man pages for git-diff that explains why this happens for name swaps only*

#### Rename the files without reusing existing names (Commit F -> H)

```
# on commit F
git mv a c
git mv b d
git commit -m "H"
```

**Then `git diff` *does* detect the renames**

```
git diff HEAD^
```

Output:

```
diff --git a/a b/c
similarity index 100%
rename from a
rename to c
diff --git a/b b/d
similarity index 100%
rename from b
rename to d
```

## Question

**How come git can detect the renames when the new names *do not* collide with file names already in the tree, but can *not* detect the renames when the new names *do* collide?**

Supplementary question: How can I detect content changes between directories (ie, `git diff --no-index dir1 dir2`), ignoring file names entirely, when files often have names swapped? At first, I thought this use case was perfectly suited to git, but I guess it is not... ([Can git use rename-detection for files that already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427959))

---

**EDIT:**
I see a common theme in comments about `git` not tracking file renames or other filesystem metadata in *commits*. I'm aware of this, and this doesn't answer the question I've posted on *why git behaves differently* when generating a diff if names are **reused** versus when names are **unique**:

Consider (outside of a repo - so there is no commit):

Directory Structure:

```
1
├── a
└── b
2
├── a
└── b
```

File 1/a:

```
a
```

File 1/b:

```
b
```

File 2/a:

```
b
```

File 2/b:

```
a
```

There is no content changed, so diff should be blank (or show the renames):

```
git diff --no-index 1 2
```

Output (but it's not):

```
diff --git a/1/a b/2/a
index 7898192..6178079 100644
--- a/1/a
+++ b/2/a
@@ -1 +1 @@
-a
+b
diff --git a/1/b b/2/b
index 6178079..7898192 100644
--- a/1/b
+++ b/2/b
@@ -1 +1 @@
-b
+a
```

However, if the directory structure is like this:

```
1
├── a
└── b
2
├── c
└── d
```

File 2/c:

```
a
```

File 2/d:

```
b
```

The diff shows only renames:

```
git diff --no-index 1 2
```

Output:

```
diff --git a/1/b b/2/c
similarity index 100%
rename from 1/b
rename to 2/c
diff --git a/1/a b/2/d
similarity index 100%
rename from 1/a
rename to 2/d
```

Comment: You're crediting Git with purpose and intelligence it doesn't have. Git doesn't actually detect or care about renames. It has some algorithm for guessing at this just in the special case when a file is deleted and another file with the same content is created, in the context of tracing a file's history back thru the chain of parent commits. But in your case that didn't even happen; nothing was deleted or created; two files were modified, that's all.

Comment: It might be able to detect it with some other flags. Renaming is something which is detected when you run commands to look at the history, not something which is actually stored in a commit.

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify what I am asking. I'm asking why the filenames matter when git produces a diff. In one case, git detects the renames (because the names are different, but content is the same) and in the other it does not (presumably because the names are reused ie, swapped). The commits are irrelevant. My use case uses ``--no-index`` option in any case. Behaviour is independent of ``--no-index`` used or not. Which is exactly what I expect as I don't care about commit history, only content. It's just weird to me that the file name matters at all to ``git diff --no-index``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why git behaves differently when generating a diff if names are reused versus when names are unique

It's because Git thinks content changes in existing files happen so much more often than renames that that's the explanation it presents, it shows the diffs as the result of content changes not renames when that explanation is easy to find.

The thing is, what it's presenting is a sequence of operations that will produce the results: its results are correct. There's clearly an infinitude of such correct sequences, that will produce one work tree from another. It's got a lot of options for minor tweaks to what it comes up with, but what you're doing will currently need manual prep, nobody's made it a built-in option.

If Git's guessing wrong, and tracking which exact sequence led to the result really matters—I see that isn't the main point for you, this is background material for the "why", skip to the end if you want—you can do the changes step by step, in a side branch to keep the the first-parent history buildable if that's an issue:

```
---B------------D  mainline
    \          /
     S1--S2--S3
```

so

```
git init `mktemp -d`; cd $_
echo a>a; echo b>b; git add .; git commit -am-

git checkout -b swap-a-b
git mv a temp; git commit -am 'swap a and b step 1'
git mv b a;    git commit -am 'swap a and b step 2'
git mv temp b; git commit -am 'swap a and b step 3'

git checkout -
git merge --no-ff -; git branch -d swap-a-b

git log --graph --decorate --oneline --name-status
git log --oneline --date-order --name-status --follow -- a
```

and in the mainline's first-parent history the swap's done in one step, the steps where the simplest explanation is the correct one for your use are in the side branch where git can show them to anyone who cares.

---

If you want to see how a file got to be what you see, you want that `--follow` option I used in the last line. You can even follow just a section of the code, you can say `git log -L 1,1:a` or `-L myinvsqrt:utils.c`

None of that will get a plain `git diff` that sees only the two tips to suspect file-swapping, though. It's looking only at the results and presenting the simplest (by its lights) set of edits that will produce them.

**Payload**

There is no way to ask `git diff` to inspect the history of changes to a file to come up with an alternate sequence of edits that would produce what it sees, but there's a very simple way to make it suspect there's renames and copies happening when that's not apparent in its quick checks:

```
git init `mktemp -d`; cd $_
echo a>a; echo b>b; git add .; git commit -m-



mkdir -p renames; git mv a renames/b; git mv b renames/a
git diff -M -C --name-status @
git diff -M -C @ # same, just much more verbose output since it's all renames
git reset --hard @
```

and if you're in a checkout that's already got the renames done, you can `git mv * renames` before diffing against the original.

Yes, this is just a much easier way to do the rename-everything-to-alert-Git step you already figured out, the main point here was to explain why.

---

<sub>p.s. heh. you could even do the rename-tracking-for-posterity commits that way, thanks, this is one of the reasons I answer questions here, explaining things makes me think harder about them. It'd let you do it quicker and easier to both do and understand: `mkdir renamed; git mv a renamed/b; git mv b renamed/a; git commit -m 'renames step 1'; git mv 'renamed/*' .; git commit -m 'renames step 2'`.</sub>

Comment: This answer seems like it will be right. I'll accept it after testing. I'm interested to see if the ``--follow`` option works as you've described. It never helped in the past BUT I never did each move (or at least each step of a swap) in a seperate commit. I feel this will work. I think it may not help my use case, as the rename approach you demonstrate is way faster. But great idea and I think is good practice in a real codebase to do it... maybe

Answer (score 0):

(I would have just commented, but my reputation was insufficient)

**(** EDIT: this answer more pertains to the info stored in a git repository than what the question was intended to focus on: the workings of the git diff tool. **)**

I agree with the first comment to the effect that git is mainly concerned with the contents of files, not the contents of file systems.

**(** EDIT: just as the git commit history is concerned, the git diff tool is mainly concerned with the file contents/content history and not the file system content/file system history.  When doing the file differentiation, the git diff tool should and is correctly showing in the question's example the file contents that have changed, not the file system changes.  Binary data such as image files are another matter, the git diff tool was not designed to diff binary data, there might be a filetype specific extension that could recognize binary data and infer file renames in those cases. **)**

Git could do something like compare file metadata such as file address table data, file create timestamp, and/or file edit time but that metadata and the situations that cause the metadata to be updated are file-system implementation specific.  Such specific git implementations would cause expected behavior inconsistencies compared to other implementations such that it is unlikely that the time to develop and maintain those rename detection behaviors compared to the additional time necessary to make sure that new undesired inconsistencies are not caused by the new rename detection functions would be usefully helpful.

One way to record for your repository history that files were renamed if it is important would be to rename the 'a' file to 'c', do a commit, then rename the 'b' file to 'a' (having selected the 'b' file as the more important of the two renames to track) and commit that, then commit the final rename 'c' to 'a'.

That would make the one rename evident with the second commit and the other rename less obvious from the two nonsequential commits.

A. intelli-speculatively, if you're using highly automated development tools to generate new development work considered better for consistency with file organizations history, that might be less testing than the multiple file system extra compatibility of multiple git implementations.  I further speculate that sort of thing is unnecessarily complicating for git-tracked source code projects.

Comment: I really am not looking for file based differencing, I only want content based differencing. Normally git does this fine. I hardly need to use -M -C etc to detect copies and renames. Only having trouble with the name swap specifically. I'm not interested in filesystem atime mtime etc at all, only content. Heck I don't even care if git tells me it was a rename or not. I just don't want the content that hasn't changed in the diff. The file names are meaningless in my use case.

Comment: I have an idea, and will test it tomorrow: I will catenate all files into one and compare the difference before and after the rename. Git has a flag to track moves, so maybe that will work. Only problem is I will end up with very large files so not sure about performance

Comment: I had a better idea... to randomize the file names. I tested it and posted as a partial answer. But I still want to know why git cares about file names...

Comment: Git works with binary data fine. Only thing to be aware of is *incompresible* data will blow out the size of your repo (same goes for text files too). As for actually diffing binary data, yes a hex diff tool is needed and the built in git diff won't show modified content (but will show the modification happened). In practice, this does rule out popular image formats, but only because they all have built in compression and *not* anything to do with being binary data. Storing raw image files without compression would not blow out the size of your repo.

Comment: That is a good point about potentially conserving repo size by allowing whole file version renames in commits.